# Qunit test using Kendo combo box, undefined

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, kendo-ui, qunit

When i am running this test using Qunit, i get this error " Cannot read property 'datasource' of undefined"
My scripts are getting loaded, i verified that, i want to be able to create combo box, add a datasource, and verify that i can bind data to that datascource

this is my test code in my javascript file:

```
/// <reference path="../qunit.js" />
/// <reference path="../jquery/jquery-2.0.3-vsdoc.js" />
/// <reference path="../jquery/jquery-2.0.3.js" />
/// <reference path="../jquery/jquery.validate.min.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../../web/scripts/Kendo/kendo.all.min.js" />


module("Kendo combo box testfunctions", {
setup: function () {
    var Div = $("#Div1");
    var selectItem = '<select id="combo"></select>';
    var kendoCombo = $("#combo");
    Div.append(selectItem);

    kendoCombo.kendoComboBox({
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "value",
        dataSource: [
            { text: "Item1", value: "1" },
            { text: "Item2", value: "2" }
        ]
    });
},
teardown: function () {
    var div = $("#div1");
    div1.remove();
}
});
test("kendo combo create", function () {
    debugger
    var dv= $("#div1");
     $("#combo").kendoCombo.kendoComboBox({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: [
        { text: "Item1", value: "1" },
        { text: "Item2", value: "2" }
    ]
});

var combobox = $("#combo").data("kendoComboBox");
    ok(combobox != undefined, "sucess Created kendo combo box");
});
```

This is my HMTL file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>

    <link href="../content/qunit.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../scripts/qunit.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/unittests/sampletests.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="qunit-header">Unit Tests</h1>
    <h2 id="qunit-banner"></h2>
    <h2 id="qunit-userAgent"></h2>
    <ol id="qunit-tests"></ol>
    <div id="qunit-fixture">test markup, will be hidden</div>

<div id="div1">


</div>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test:

```
var k = $('#combo');
k.kendoCombo.kendoComboBox({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: [
        { text: "Item1", value: "1" },
        { text: "Item2", value: "2" }
    ]
});

var combobox = k.data("kendoComboBox").datasource;
```

what do you expect `k.kendoCombo` to be? You're trying to get the widget from `k`, so you probably want to create your combobox on that element, i.e.:

```
var k = $('#combo');
k.kendoComboBox({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: [
        { text: "Item1", value: "1" },
        { text: "Item2", value: "2" }
    ]
});

var combobox = k.data("kendoComboBox").dataSource; // also note the upper case S in the dataSource property
```

Your code is pretty confusing overall - why do you assign the combobox data source to the `combobox` var?

Comment: if you look at the kendo UI demo, this is how they create a kendo combo box from HTML element...http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/combobox/index.html, that is why i do..'k.kendoCombo'

Comment: I updated my code, K is just a var, instead of doing $('#combo')

Comment: @WingMan20-10 I get that `k` was a var, but your edit hasn't really clarified anything and so the issue is still the same - what do you expect  `$("#combo").kendoCombo` to be? The jQuery element doesn't have a `kendoCombo` property. Did you try my suggested change?

Comment: if you look at the link i gave, this is how telerik does it in the example, this is how they create a comobo box in javascript...

Comment: they do `$("#fabric").kendoComboBox()`, not `$("#fabric").kendoCombo.kendoComboBox()`